# Running puma from god configuration file is giving no application configured error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monitoring, daemon, puma, god

Hi i am using god to monitor the processes. I want to monitor puma. The problem is it is giving me this error: 'ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run' on starting puma. 
Same command when i am using manually, puma is starting up successfully.

God Configuration file for reference:

```
w.name = "puma"
w.interval = 60.seconds
w.start = "RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec puma -C #{RAILS_ROOT}/config/puma.rb"

w.stop = "kill -s QUIT $(cat #{pid_file})"
w.restart = "kill -s HUP $(cat #{pid_file})"
w.start_grace = 20.seconds
w.restart_grace = 20.seconds
w.pid_file = pid_file
w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)
```

I have defined the pid_file above.

Comment: Does this file is in your application?